# Regarding the Definition of a Diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Michal Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry - Vol 1" where he defines two manifolds $(M,A)$ and $(N,B)$ (where $A,B$ are the maximum atlases) to be diffeomorphic when there is a bijection $f:M \to N$ s.t. $x\in B$ iff $x\circ f \in A$. My question is that if the manifolds are diffeomorphic does that imply that every chart in $A$ is of the form $x\circ f$ for $x\in B$?

Intuitively my guess is that the statement is correct since $A$,$B$ are maximal atlases, and because the two manifolds are supposed to be "the same" just maybe constructed differently, though I haven't the slightest idea how to even prove such a thing.

Comment: Suppose $\varphi$ is a chart in $M$. Then $\varphi = x \circ f $ with  $x=\varphi \circ f^{-1}$.